# Is it good or bad practice to have multiple foreign keys in a single table, when the other tables can be connected using joins?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, join

Let's say I wanted to make a database that could be used to keep track of bank accounts and transactions for a user. A database that can be used in a Checkbook application.

If i have a user table, with the following properties:

1. user_id
2. email
3. password

And then I create an account table, which can be linked to a certain user:

1. account_id
2. account_description
3. account_balance
4. user_id

And to go the next step, I create a transaction table:

1. transaction_id
2. transaction_description
3. is_withdrawal
4. account_id // The account to which this transaction belongs
5. user_id // The user to which this transaction belongs

Is having the user_id in the transaction table a good option? It would make the query cleaner if I wanted to get all the transactions for each user, such as:

```
SELECT * FROM transactions
JOIN users ON users.user_id = transactions.user_id
```

Or, I could just trace back to the users table from the account table

```
SELECT * FROM transactions
JOIN accounts ON accounts.account_id = transactions.account_id
JOIN users ON users.user_id = accounts.user_id
```

I know the first query is much cleaner, but is that the best way to go?

My concern is that by having this extra (redundant) column in the transaction table, I'm wasting space, when I can achieve the same result without said column.

Comment: Ah, the great normalised vs denormalised debate. Usually, the decision to go denormalised is due to a concern for runtime performance. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization. If speed is no concern for you, using normalised data keeps data in a centralised place, meaning more consistency.

Comment: So it seems like this is really a matter of opinion then? If not opinion, but a matter of which is more important, speed or consistency?

Comment: Keep it normalised. Your "cleaner" query makes other things (e.g. inserts) more complicated. It's also counter intuitive to others working with your DB. If you find you have a quadrillion users and you need to optimise it then visit it later. The bottleneck is often not where you thought it was (and at that scale, maybe even your entire DB system needs changing).

Comment: Only time I would consider storing the userID in the transaction table would be if this were a data warehouse situation (IE, this is a copy of the data and you're intentionally denormalizing to ease reporting). Otherwise use the join and keep it normalized

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's look at it from a different angle. From where will the query or series of queries start? If you have customer info, you can get account info and then transaction info or just transactions-per-customer. You need all three tables for meaningful information. If you have account info, you can get transaction info and a pointer to customer. But to get any customer info, you need to go to the customer table so you still need all three tables. If you have transaction info, you could get account info but that is meaningless without customer info or you could get customer info without account info but transactions-per-customer is useless noise without account data.

Either way you slice it, the information you need for any conceivable use is split up between three tables and you will have to access all three to get meaningful information instead of just a data dump.

Having the customer FK in the transaction table may provide you with a way to make a "clean" query, but the result of that query is of doubtful usefulness. So you've really gained nothing. I've worked writing Anti-Money Laundering (AML) scanners for an international credit card company, so I'm not being hypothetical. You're always going to need all three tables anyway.

Btw, the fact that there are FKs in the first place tells me the question concerns an OLTP environment. An OLAP environment (data warehouse) doesn't need FKs or any other data integrity checks as warehouse data is static. The data originates from an OLTP environment where the data integrity checks have already been made. So there you can denormalize to your hearts content. So let's not be giving answers applicable to an OLAP environment to a question concerning an OLTP environment.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the OLAP/OLTP insight, that definitely sheds a new light on the situation. However, it seems that normalizing this is still the way to go, because if I'm going to need three tables regardless, why waste the column when I don't need it? The normalized query is after all, only one line different. The whole normalized/denormalized debate is new to me, I had no idea I was asking such a double sided question, but I have learned so much from this one.

Comment: Oh yeah. The normalize/denormalize religious war has been waging the full two decades I've been playing around databases.

I agree that the extra column is a waste but even more than that. Data is a lot like code in that it must be as complicated as it needs to be to get the job done, but adding complexity beyond that point is, well, counter-indicated.

Answer (score 4):

You should not use two foreign keys in the same table. This is not a good database design.

A user makes transactions through an account. That is how it is logically done; therefore, this is how the DB should be designed.

Using joins is how this should be done. You should not use the `user_id` key as it is already in the account table.

The wasted space is unnecessary and is a bad database design.

Comment: Agreed. A user has 1 or more accounts. Each account can have 1 or more transactions. The transaction belongs to the account not the user.

Comment: The only way you would have two foreign keys is if the accounts table did not have the user_id associated with it

Comment: +1 for pointing out the logic, that's what drove me to the question. I realized that logically I could figure out who the user of each transaction was, because I know the account of the transaction. But of course I then realized it would be faster if I could store the user_id in the transactions table. It seems like this is the best way to go, though. It's most logical, and most efficient, both of which (I personally believe) are more important than simply speed.

Comment: I'd ask if the account can change users, or if that information is permanent.  Old-school transaction tables are often meant to be historically inclusive for that sort of reason.  That is, if you want to know who executed a transaction, you'd put in the user_id, if there's any mechanism by which the user and account could be separated years later.  If there's NO mechanism by which that could happen, then you should ask why they are two tables in the first place (there may be good answers).  It depends on the use case, though.

Comment: I don't foresee any situations where an account would change users. Interesting point though, about whether or not there is a need for other tables. I think personally it would help with simplicity and displaying any information. Instead of one big table, where I'd have complicated queries and subqueries to view just users, or just accounts, I can separate that data into multiple tables.

Comment: I don't think it is even possible to change an account holder without the owner of the account closing the account. You can have multiple users per account but you cannot change the actual account holder

Answer (score 2):

Denormalizing is usually a bad idea. In the first place it is often not faster from a performance standard. What it does is make the data integrity at risk and it can create massive problems if you end up changing from a 1-1 relationship to a 1-many.

For instance what is to say that each account will have only one user?  In your table design that is all you would get which is something I find suspicious right off the bat. Accounts in my system can have thousands of users. SO that is the first place I question your model. Did you actually think interms of whether the realtionships woudl be 1-1 or 1-many? Or did you just make an asssumpltion? Datamodels are NOT easy to adjust after you have millions of records, you need to do far more planning for the future in database design and far more thinking about the data needs over time than you do in application design.

But suppose you have one-one relationship now. And three months after you go live you get a new account where they need to have 3 users. Now you have to rememeber all the places you denornmalized in order to properly fix the data. This can create much confusion as inevitably you will forget some of them.

Further even if you never will need to move to a more robust model, how are you going to maintain this if the user_id changes as they are going to do often. Now in order to keep the data integrity, you need to have a trigger to maintain the data as it changes. Worse, if the data can be changed from either table you could get conflicting changes. How do you handle those?

So you have created a maintenance mess and possibly risked your data intergrity all to write "cleaner" code and save yourself all of ten seconds writing a join? You gain nothing in terms of things that are important in database development such as performance or security or data integrity and you risk alot.  How short-sighted is that?

You need to stop thinking in terms of "Cleaner code" when developiong for databases. Often the best code for a query is the most complex appearing as it is the most performant and that is critical for databases. Don't project object-oriented coding techniques into database developement, they are two very differnt things with very differnt needs.  You need to start thinking in terms of how this will play out as the data changes which you clearly are not doing or you would not even consider doing such a thing. You need to think more of thr data meaning and less of the "Principles of software development" which are taught as if they apply to everything  but in reality do not apply well to databases.

Comment: FWIW: After working a good bit in SQL, I find "cleaner code" *is* often the model with more joins. It is the query tooling and DAL that needs to keep up, not the database that needs to be dumb'ed down. I find the summary very fitting and have personally run into "massive problems" in denormalized designs - give me normalized relationships (for any OLTP).

Answer (score 1):

It depends.  If you can get the data fast enough, used the normalized version (where user_id is NOT in the transaction table).  If you are worried about performance, go ahead and include user_ID.  It will use up more space in the database by storing redundant information, but you will be able to return the data faster.

**EDIT**

There are several factors to consider when deciding whether or not to denormalize a data structure.  Each situation needs to be considered uniquely; no answer is sufficient without looking at the specific situation (hence the "It depends" that begins this answer).  For the simple case above, denormalization would probably not be an optimal solution.

Comment: Thanks. I imagine normalization is probably the way to go. Of course, that can vary based on size of the database, right? A small enough database can make that join quickly, but as the amount of rows grows and grows (assonance unintended) speed may be increased by denormalization.

Comment: You do NOT want to call it this way. The only way you should is if you were linking the primary keys from the account and user tables to the transaction table. You should NEVER use the primary key and foreign of the same table is another table

Comment: denormalization is demonstrably not faster in many cases (there are technical issues concenring page splits, etc that come to mind) and performance must also be measured on inserts updates and adeletes which are much slower in denomralized schemes in order to gkeep the data integrity. PLease do not keep putting out the myth that denormalized will be faster.

Comment: @user2864740 - You are free to believe that, but the fact of the matter is that many businesses denormalize to improve performance.  See [Lesson 3: Optimizing the Database Design by Denormalizing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc505841.aspx) from MSDN.  A simple Google query will return hundreds more valid results.  I understand you seem to be looking to get your point across here, but the fact of the matter is that certain data structures lend themselves to denormalization (especially in an OLAP environment).

Comment: The OP gave a very simplistic example, and I gave a general answer.  Sorry if you felt like I oversimplified it.  Let's face it, you aren't going to learn expert performance tuning by posting a single question on SO.  Would you be happier if I added a note that each situation is unique and needs to be evaluated before deciding whether or not to denormalize a data structure?

Comment: Thanks for the update. My objections have been adequately softened.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, if you have simple Many-To-Many relation just use two primary keys, and that's all.

Otherwise, if you have Many-To-Many relation with extra columns use one primary key, and two foreign keys. It's easier to manage this table as single Entity, just like Doctrine do it. Generally speaking simple Many-To-Many relations are rare, and they are usefull just for linking two tables.

Comment: You can't have two primary keys. I think you mean a composite key?